# Is there any FlymeOS or MIUI emulator?

Tags: android, sdk, miui

I'm testing my android application. 
Problem: Is there any way to test application with FlymeOS, MIUI without having physical device? 
Reason: FlymeOS for example have some security differences, and what applicable for pure android, may not be applicable for FlymeOS.

I have already tried to do that with GennyMotion, Android Studio emulators.